# Get last element of an array which not null

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array and I would like to find an simple way to return the last occurrence of a key when "time_reported" is not NULL .

Example: for the array below the output should be the key n°2 cause it's the last array when a value is assigned.

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => 'DOGAL',
    'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 01:35:00',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => '54/20',
    'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 02:10:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => '52/30',
    'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 02:20:00',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => '49/40',
    'time_reported' => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => '47/50',
    'time_reported' => NULL,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'point_name' => 'PORTI',
    'time_reported' => NULL,
  ),
)
```

I already had the idea to use a foreach loop to find the last occurrence but I don't know if it's the most efficient way to do that

Comment: Tip: It helps us a lot if you present the array as PHP code we can use for testing and not as this debug output which is completely useless for that purpose.

Comment: thanks for the tip @tadman , modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is in order, you can just traverse it until `$item["time_reported"]` is not null.  This will get it done in O(N) in the worst case.  If the array is not sorted, and you need the earliest / latest time, you will need to look at every element in the array for a best (and every) case of O(N).

```
$a = array(...);
for ($i = count($a) - 1; $i > 0 && $a[$i]["time_reported"] === null; $i--);
echo "Found at index {$i}\n";
```

Comment: The problem with this method is, when the key n° 0 is the last occurence, the loop return nothing.. Do you have a solution for that ? @Alexb

Comment: @MagicNesquick simplified the example to handle this edge case.  You just need to use the value of `$i` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using foreach loop we can use `array_reverse` function so we can reverse the array, looping the last array to first. Then check if the key values is null or empty. You can see the result [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1FzZrqiS).

```
<?php

$myarrays = array( array (
                        'point_name' => 'DOGAL',
                        'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 01:35:00',
                      ),
                      array (
                        'point_name' => '54/20',
                        'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 02:10:00',
                      ),
                     array (
                        'point_name' => '52/30',
                        'time_reported' => '2019-11-14 02:20:00',
                      ),
                      array (
                        'point_name' => '49/40',
                        'time_reported' => NULL,
                      ),
                      array (
                        'point_name' => '47/50',
                        'time_reported' => NULL,
                      ),
                      array (
                        'point_name' => 'PORTI',
                        'time_reported' => NULL,
                      ),
             );

             #echo "<pre>";
             #print_r($myarrays);

             foreach ( array_reverse($myarrays) as $array ) {
              if($array['time_reported'] !== NULL){
                  echo $array['point_name']."\n";
                  echo $array['time_reported'];
                  break 1; // stop the loop
              }

             }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this too:**

```
 function getLastNotNullValueInArray($array)
    {
        $reversed = array_reverse($array);
        foreach($reversed as $arrValue)
        {
            if($arrValue)
                return  $arrValue;
        }
        return false;
    }
```